# Flutter Web - Set State - File Picker - File Name / File Name is not showing when File Picker picks file. Is SetState applied correctly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, setstate

I am very new to flutter and coding. This may be an easy fix but I cannot find a solution anywhere or reconfigure the code to display the name of the file I am picking.

I am trying to create a web page that can accept document submissions. However, I cannot get the code to display the name of the file picked.

The print call is working, however, the fileNameSelected does not update.

Thank you for any help!!

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:io' as io; //type cast

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

import './appbar/appbar.dart';

class UploadFPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadFPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UploadFPage> createState() => _UploadFPageState();
}

class _UploadFPageState extends State<UploadFPage> {
  UploadTask? task;
  File? file;
  String fileNameSelected = 'No File Selected';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fileName = fileNameSelected;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('AppBar'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 300,
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.attach_file, size: 28),
                  onPressed: selectFile,
                  label: Text("Attach Invoice"),
                ),
                Text(fileName),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future selectFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowedExtensions: ['pdf']);

    if (result == null) {
      return;
    } else {
      print(result.files.single.name);
      //final name = result.files.single.name;
      //final path = result.files.single.path!;
      //final file = result.files.single.bytes!;

      setState(() {
        String fileNameSelected = basename(result.files.single.name);
        //file = File(size, path);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
  setState(() {
    String fileNameSelected = basename(result.files.single.name);
  });
```

to

```
  setState(() {
    fileNameSelected = basename(result.files.single.name);
  });
```

By adding `var`, `final` or `String` in front you are declaring a new variable (which happens to have the same name as the one you declared above). You assign your picked file to that - and it promptly goes out of scope.

Comment: Wow... Thank you. Sincerely, thank you!